# Liaison between indirect and direct objects

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, liaisons

I found this sentence on Wikipedia under the impossible liaison section (with the explanation that *liaison is impossible between two complements of a ditransitive verb*)

> donner des **cadeaux à** Jean /dɔ.ne de ka.do (.z‿) a ʒɑ̃/ ("give presents to Jean")

And here's just a sentence with a similar thing going on

> Je dois deux **euros à** Paul. /ʒə dwa dø (.z‿) ø.ʀo a pɔl/ ("I owe Paul two euros.")

I checked many websites but I haven't found any information at all about such a case, can anyone help? Is the liaison optional or forbidden in this case?

Comment: The categorising  "Liaison between indirect and direct objects" is not correct; those grammatical categories are not determining factors in the context of liaisons; the  criteria in determining whether or not a liaison is made are found in phonetics and usage, not grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Ceci est un cas général de liaison qui ne se pratique pas ([Académie Française](http://academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#46_strong-em-liaisons-em-strong)) ;

> Elle ne se pratique pas
>
> - après le s intérieur dans les locutions nominales au pluriel : des moulins à vent, des fers à repasser, les machines à laver ;

- (optionnelle)  des lignes étroites, les flammes énormes,
- (à ne pas faire) des feux oranges, des fruits aqueux, des seaux à eau, des choix à n'en plus finir, …

Dans la question il ne s'agit pas de locution nominales, mais la syntaxe est apparentée. (*Les cadeaux à Jean sont sur la table.* (familier, registre courant : cadeaux **de** Jean))

À partir de « [Études littéraires](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/regles-de-liaison.php) » en cliquant « etc. » dans la section « Liaisons fautives » on obtient le complément suivant sur les [liaisons fautives](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/liaison.html#interdites), encore appelées interdites ou déconseillées ; parmi l'ensemble assez détaillé se trouve la règle la plus générale pour les liaisons qui ne se font pas ;

> Les liaisons ne se font pas entre deux groupes de mots dont l'un complète l'autre et principalement lorsque celui-ci est en tête.
> Sur les pistes éclairées/ atterrissaient les avions.

**mot principal après, liaison**

- de fines arrêtes, les longs établis, d'étroites étendues,

**mot principal avant, pas de liaison**

- des arrêtes abruptes, des établis assortis, les étendues arables,

Cette règle est une exception, comme elle est basée sur un principe de syntaxe.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence has a liaison.

PS: Should your title not be more generally about 'liaison between direct and indirect objects?'?

Comment: Thank you! I guess it makes sense because these words are not syntactically related. Also, I changed the title, so thanks for that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be wrong to add a liaison between the two complements in either of these sentences.